# Will Geolocations for IPs ever change?

Tags: multiplayer, server, geolocation

I'm making a game where the geographic location of a user is used to give them a little flag icon next to their user name. To do this, I've been using the [ipstack API](https://ipstack.com/). However, the API only allows up to 10,000 requests per month, and since I make a request every time a user connects, this could easily lead to overuse.

Would it make sense to just store geolocation data on my server and only make a request when an unknown IP connects? Or will the geolocation data ever change for an IP?

Comment: This isn't really a question specific to game development. But I am not sure which site it should be on. Maybe [network engineering stack exchange](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com) because it is a question about IP allocation? But [they are very elitist](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Be sure to double-check the licensing terms of the API you're using, as they might have rules about how much of their data you're allowed to store persistently or how you're allowed to do it (after all, they don't want someone to duplicate large portions of their data set — they want you to pay for increased access limits)

Comment: @DMGregory I'll do it, thanks for the tip. I didn't think about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is partially answered [over here](https://serverfault.com/questions/59167/how-often-do-ip-blocks-get-reassigned-to-different-regions). In short: don't count on consistency. IPs probably don't get re-assigned/moved often, but services might change their algorithms, have bugs, etc.

Realistically, unless the perfect consistency of this data is critical to your game, you should be able to get away with caching prior results.

A reasonable hybrid strategy would be to store the result of the call and the time it was made with the rest of a user's data. Then when a user logs in with a last-checked date older than some threshold, refresh it. You could also maintain an internal ledger of how many API requests you have remaining for the month, holding some portion in reserve for new users.

Comment: This is a good idea. I'm going to go ahead and implement this method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, IP addresses can change their physical location. ISPs sometimes trade blocks of IP addresses between each other. A large ISP might also change its regional IP address allocations for internal reasons. But this happens quite rarely.

But keep in mind that IP addresses are registerd block-wise. IP blocks [get assigned to continents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_assigned_/8_IPv4_address_blocks). The regional internet registires then usually break these blocks into subnets which get assigned to countries which then get broken up into sub-subnets which get assigned to ISPs. So when you just want to know the country of the user and not the exact city, then you just need to know the country the IP *range* with the user's IP is allocated to. There are many databases around which map IP ranges to countries. [They are not hard to find with search engines](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=ip%20address%20by%20country) and they are not so large that they wouldn't fit inside your application.

Comment: The city is pretty important to me, so this isn't really an option for me. I did look into doing this exact thing it before going with ipstack, for what it's worth.